# Regex to accept digits from 0 to 20 including 1 or 2 decimal numbers in C#

Tags: regex

I am trying to get `regex` which can validate a) accepted numbers should be between 0 to 20 and b) these numbers can have 1 or 2 decimal numbers.

RegEx:

```
^(10|\d)(\.\d{1,2})?$
(10|\d) allows for a single digit or 10
(\.\d{1,2})? possible decimal followed by 1 or 2 digits
```

This gives me desired result from 0 to 10 (http://regexr.com/). I am not sure what needs to modify if I want it to accept from 0 to 20.

Valid:

```
0
1
2 or 2.5
20
```

Invalid:

```
21
.1
.0345
```

This is what I have tried:

```
1. ^\d{0,2}$(\.\d{1,2})?$
- Accepts 0 to 99 but no decimal

2. ^([1-9]|20)$
- Accepts 1 to 9 only
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?:1?\d(?:\.\d{1,2})?|20(?:\.0?0?)?)$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UzZAMo/6)

- `(?:1?\d)` - will match number in the range `0-19`
- `(?:\.\d{1,2})?` - will allow optional 1 or 2 decimal numbers.
- `20(?:\.0?0?)?` - will match `20` with optional zeroes after decimal point.

Comment: Perfect. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: I've noticed that this regex accepts values which are greater than 20 but less than 21. e.g, 20.15, 20.99

Comment: there is a missing case which is that of a number with the dot. Ex: "3." or "19."

Comment: @A.Morel: `3.` or `19.` case is not in OP's requirement otherwise that is not difficult to account for in this regex.

Comment: @anubhava how ? When I write in my field "3" then "3." in order to write "3.32" for example, I can't write more than "3", I'm blocked.

Comment: @A.Morel: Use `^(?:1?\d(?:\.\d{1,2})?\.?|20(?:\.0{0,2})?)$` regex